# Necesito ayuda con laravel y jquery y ajax, estoy aprendiendo me podran dar una mano

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  estoy tratando de hacer un enviar de un form de un solo campo email con ajax y jquery pero no lo logro hacer función, no me envía alguien me puede ayudar, es la primera vez que trabajo con ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el script del formulario

Comment: Además si tu código no esta funcionando entonces ayudaría mucho que compartieras que error estás obteniendo por ejemplo en la consola

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo los métodos done(), fail(), always() en tu petición y trata de ordenar el código, veo que en el form hay dos input y uno no tiene el atributo name. Si vas usar jQuery para manipular el DOM que así sea:

```
document.getElementById('contact_us').reset();
$('#contact_us')[0].reset();
```

Intenta con este script:

```
$('#contact_us').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        let url = "/correo";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //respuesta exitosa del servidor
                //código con la respuesta del servidor
            }
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                //código cuando se complete el request
                console.log('ERROR: ' + response.err);
                $('#contact_us')[0].reset();
            })
            .fail(function (response) {
                //código cuando falle el request
                console.log('ERROR: ' + response.err);
            })
            .always(function () {
                //código que se ejecuta siempre request exitoso o request erroneo
                console.log("COMPLETE");
                $('#contact_us')[0].reset();
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta ahi probare :)